# What is the meaning of this Entity Framework exception?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception

What is the meaning of this exception? Where can I find references of the cause to this kind of exception?

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while
>       updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. 
>       Inner exception message: Metadata information for the relationship 
>       'MyModel.FK_T_WORKER_VEHICLE_T_VEHICLE' could not be retrieved. If mapping attributes are used, make sure that the
>   EdmRelationshipAttribute for the relationship has been defined in the
>   assembly.  When using convention-based mapping, metadata information
>   for relationships between detached entities cannot be determined.
>       Parameter name: relationshipName

I am using edmx with code generation set to Default. The pocos are in different project then the edmx file.

Comment: I think it means your edmx or generated code is busted. See this question for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350514/ef-mapping-and-metadata-information-could-not-be-found-for-entitytype-error

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: What do you mean by "Busted"? I looked on the link but nothing there helped.. do you have any idea what can I do in order to solve this issue?

Comment: "busted" means "broken" or "non-functional".

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: Where can I find the problem?.. How can I test it?

Comment: How are you accomplishing POCOs in a different project *and* code generation set to default?  Those sound mutually exclusive to me, and sound like a possible source of errors in keeping the edmx, entities, and DB in sync.  When I said it is busted, I mean your objects, edmx, and or DB are out of sync with each other.  Search through one or all of them by reading the error message - look for the objects that define that foreign-key relationship.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: You know, I am looking in my code again and again. In the application_start (global.asax) I inject MyAppEntities (the context) which generated automatically by the edmx and I really don't know how the entity framework knows to use my pocos.. And it works.. the EF returns allways my objects.. (in addition to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839682/how-to-configure-entity-framework-poco-with-similar-names). Any idea?..

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Ok. I think I understand now. Look in my Repository<T> class (you can find it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/entity-framework-with-repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern-and-poco-architecture under MyApp.Data.EF4 section). There is a property called 'ObjectSet' and it use: '_objectSet = this.Context.CreateObjectSet<T>();'. When I instanciate the repository with my poco, it create objectset in type of my poco and not the generated code. What do you think?

Comment: @Naor: I think you should either ditch your POCOs and use the generated code (which should have the correct attributes), or ditch the EDMX and go purely code-first.  Mixing the two seems like it could be made to work, but would not be well supported, and would give you a lot of headache for little to no benefit.  There's some videos on the front page of the EF site demoing the code-first option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Thanks for the suggestion but this is a project that already running with database and data. I prefer my pocos because they represent my business logic and I added there more abilities. If I understand correct, I actually don't use the abilities of the Context that the designer generated for me.. Am I right?..

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: You know, I set the Code Generation Strategy to None and added an empty class called "test" that inherit from ObjectContext. And the application worked. I even don't need the generated code. Unfortunately this exception continues showing up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got same error when I added a new entity(A) to my EDMX diagram  which A has Foreign key reference to an existing entity B. Then this error came up when I tried to do CRUD for B.
I did some researches and followed a tip on [MetadataException when using Entity Framework Entity Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074337/metadataexception-when-using-entity-framework-entity-connection) which advises to rename metadata in Connection String but it didn't work for me.
**Steps to resolve:**
The issue was in entity A not B. You need to check newly added entity A to be mapped correctly to your class A in your domain. Check property names and property types to be same (i.e. a column might need to be converted to an Enum type in your diagram to be same with your entity). Keep in mind that property names are **case sensitive** so if they are in upper-case in your entity it should be in upper-case in your diagram.

Comment: yeah that makes sense after 3 years :)  
just thought it could be useful for whoever search this issue and come across to this page.