# MVC Test Error with EDMX Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new MVC solution, added Unit Tests, a database model (EDMX) and repository code.

I just added one very simple Unit Test to confirm that the Repository will pass Unit Testing and it keeps failing with this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Mapping and metadata information could not be
>   found for EntityType 'rlb.Models.rlb_Logins'.

Entity Framework is installed for both projects.

The failing code looks like this:

```
public BaseRepository()
{
    dbContext = new DbContext("mapbsEntities");

    // Unit Test Fails here
    _objectSet = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
}
```

Controller code that is being tested:

```
public ActionResult RepoTest()
{
    rlb_LoginsRepository<rlb_Logins> rlb_LoginsRepo = new rlb_LoginsRepository<rlb_Logins>();
    rlb_Logins loginsRecord = rlb_LoginsRepo.Find(m => m.nid == 1).FirstOrDefault();

    ViewBag.Message = loginsRecord.cLogin;
    return View();
}
```

And finally the Unit Test Code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoginsTest()
{
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();
    ViewResult result = controller.RepoTest() as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("mylogin", result.ViewBag.Message);
}
```

The code works in production ... but would like to get this Unit Tested before we start coding.

TIA,
Mark

Comment: Do you have the proper connection string in the config file? plus if making calls to the actual database then that is an integration test not a unit test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350514/ef-mapping-and-metadata-information-could-not-be-found-for-entitytype-error)

Comment: Integration test is correct phrase, but the link above doesn't help as the "blog" that it is linked too, has moved and unavailable.

Comment: Forget the bolg. check the answers provided and see if they are of use.