# Adding an inherited entity to the DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've this entity

```
public class FooEntity
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I need to extend FooEntity with new fields like this

```
public class FooExtended : FooEntity
{
  public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

but I don't want to persist the *Age* value in the database, it's used only temporarily in the model of the view.

When I try to add an instance of *FooExtended* to the DBContext

```
context.FooEntity.Add(xxx);
```

I get the following exception

> "Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType
>   'FooExtended'."

I tried adding the attribute *[NotMapped]* to the field *Age* but I get the same exception.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with Entity Framework 6.1.3?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.FooEntity.Add(xxx as FooEntity);
```

Comment: The cast is redundant

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Comment: @vcRobe The cast will hide the Age property. That way the dbContext will not know about the Age property. Remember that the EntityFramework can also map inheritted members to Tables. And this is what the exception says.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NotMapped] attribute to exclude a property from the context. You don't need to use inheritance in this case. You can read more about it [HERE](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

```
public class FooEntity
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   [NotMapped]
   public int Age { set; get; }
}
```

If you are really persistent on this inheritance thing you may do this:

```
context.FooEntity.Add(
    new FooEntity {
      ID = xxx.ID,
      Name = xxx.Name
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm using inheritance because I'm using *Age* only in a particular view

Comment: **I tried adding the attribute [NotMapped] to the field Age but I get the same exception.**

Comment: I still think the proper way would be to include it as a property on the FooEntity class it self. You can still make it nullable (int?)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Its seems to be any of the one below reasons could cause your problem. these are :

```
   Misspelled properties (case-sensitive!) 

   Properties missing in the POCO class 

   Type mismatches between the POCO and entity-type (e.g.,int instead of long) 

   Enums in the POCO (EF doesn't support enums right now as I understand)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439550/3397630

Hope It may redirect you to the correct direction

Thanks

Karthik